# Any trick to calculating percentages when the base is a negative number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I am trying to calculate percent change when the base number (at time 1) can be a negative and the resulting number is positive (at time 2).

My problem is the percent changes from -4 to +4.

A change from +4 to -4 reports back a -200% change. However, the same formula `A1/B1-1` when `A1` equals `-4` and `B2` equals `4` is also reported as -200% but it should be a 200% increase.

The ABS function does not solve this. Has anyone crafted a fix for this?

Comment: are you applying ABS to the result itself or an operand?

Comment: What's the application? For instance, what if the base number is 0? For instance if you're using this on net income or another monetary base, you may need a more elegant solution

Comment: Ok, what exactly are you looking for? Can you provide more examples of the base number, and what you want the percentage change to be?

Comment: This is not a meaningful statistic.  See Help from the WSJ Digest of Earnings regarding Net Income:  http://online.wsj.com/public/resources/documents/doe-help.htm#netincome.  They do not report percent change if current or past income show a loss.

Answer (score 5):

If `A1` is the old value and `B1` the new one:

```
=(B1 - A1) / Abs(A1)
```

Comment: This is correct for *most* scenarios

Comment: Thanks Mr. Kemper and Raysafarian.  It is a financial analyis.  If A1 is -4 and B1 is +4 then using the suggested fix is (4 - -4) / 4 will achieve 200% but my equation also subtracts 1 after the ABS(A1) which would yield 100%.  I am showing the percent change from the base rather than the result bing x percent larger or smaller than the base.  Reversing the above would be (-4 - 4) / 4 = -200% then I subtract 1 and get -300%.  I may have to recharacterize the result.  Thanks.  Any additional thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: @JohnH. what do you mean? 200% is *correct*. Why are you subtracting 1? What do you mean `percent change from base rather than the result being x percent larger or smaller than the base`? Do you have a different base number?

Comment: @Raystafarian - I am calculating the percentage change in profits from one quarter to the next.  If Q1 profit is 2 and Q2 profit is 4 then the answer can be stated two ways - Q2 profit is 200% larger than Q1 or Q2 profit increased 100% from Q1.  The issue is when Q1 profit is -2 and Q2 profit is 4.  This results in a negative percentage even though profits increased and in reality Q2 profit is 300% higher if you consider -2 to O plus 0 to 4. JohnH

Comment: @Axel Kemper, Raystafarian, Frank Thomas, and Jerry.  I solved it with and IF statement to take into account if quarter1 is negative and quarter2 is positive by using an ABS statement or if quarter1 is positive and quarter2 is either positive or negative.  It works as follows:

Comment: @Continued:  =IF(Q1<0,(Q2+ABS(Q1))/ABS(Q1),Q2/Q1-1)
Thanks to all for pushing my thinking in order to help me solve this.

Comment: @JohnH. Excellent. If you solved it, put your formula as an answer and mark it solved so if anyone else runs into this, they'll see the solution.

Comment: The community bot keeps recycling this question.  Just to clarify the OP's confusion, he was using A1 as the new value, B1 as the old value, which was the opposite convention of this answer, and then not catching that the arithmetic was the same.  His A1/B1 - 1 = (A1-B1)/B1, which is equivalent to this answer without the ABS function.  Not noticing that fact led to unnecessary complication for his own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Excel where A1 is the new value and B1 is the old value:

> ```
> =IFERROR(IF(AND(A2<0,B2<0,A2>B2),((A2-B2)/B2)*-1,IF(AND(A2<0,B2<0,A2>B2),  
> ((A2-B2)/B2),IF(AND(A2<0,B2<0),((A2-B2)/B2)*-1,IF(AND(A2>0,B2<0),((A2-B2)/B2)*-1,IF(B2<A2,((A2-B2)  
> /B2),IF(B2>A2,((A2-B2)/B2),ABS(((A2-B2)/B2))))))))*100,"")
> ```

Explanation:
The above formula is basically this formula ((A2-B2)/B2)*100 
But it only calculates positive numbers
But if you want to know the change percentage for all numbers  my given formula will solve the issue  and it handles all below situations:

1. A>0, B>0, A
2. A>0, B>0, A>B
3. A<0, B>0, |A|
4. A<0, B>0, |A|>B
5. A>0, B<0, A<|B|
6. A>0, B<0, A>|B|
7. A<0, B<0, |A|<|B|
8. A<0, B<0, |A|>|B|

Comment: This is a ton of formula with no explanation, not a very good answer.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Prior + “%change“ * ABS(Prior) = Current

Where “%change” is defined as
(Current - Prior)/ABS(Prior)

Current and or Prior can be positive or negative, but Prior cannot be zero.

Answer (score 0):

The following [article](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/ghalimi_relative-growth-activity-6755853400505749504-EanF) provides a detailed explanation as to why the (b-a)/ABS(a) formula makes sense.

Comment: Answers should be self containing, please include the key points from the article in your answer

Comment: @MátéJuhász, I will, as soon as I convert my LaTeX code to plain text.

Comment: Here is @IsmaelGhalimi's answer in full: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3986352